# How does scoring work in Plague Inc on PC?

Tags: plague-inc-evolved

What determines how many Biohazards you get for a playthrough or a scenario in Plague Inc on PC? How does scoring exactly work?

Comment: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/156833/how-to-get-5-biohazards-in-plague-inc is the same question for the mobile version. Not a dupe of course and may not be relevant but worth a read.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to http://icspicy.blogspot.com/2014/05/plague-inc-black-death-scenario-mega.html:

In order to get a 3 biohazard score in mega-brutal, you'll have to finish within about 350-360 days with a cure completion of less than 60%.

According to http://steamcommunity.com/app/246620/discussions/0/558754260052055707/:

You earn 3 Biohazards with at least these victory-parameters:

- Time: 376 days
- Cure Progress: 29%
- Final Score: 65500

According to [How to get 5 biohazards?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/156833/how-to-get-5-biohazards-in-plague-inc):

Score is based on several factors but the two main factors are the final cure percentage and the difficulty level.